# How to output mysqli query rows in inline blocks?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

I would like to output mysqli query rows, like 4 divs/spans inline and then it goes to next line, outputs next 4 divs/spans and so on. How can I do this ? what should I echo, and/or what kind of operators should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it isn't a programming issue, but design. You'll need a container with a determined width, and then you can create divs which float aside with the width (%) you need.

Like this:

```
<div class="container">
    {for}
    <div class="col-4">echo field</div>
    {next}
</div>
```

And, in your CSS, something like:

```
.container{width: 1070px}
.col-4{float: left; width: 25%}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for basic question. I just got confused and couldn't find answer at all. Its a lot easier than i thought, thank you !

Comment: No problem. By the way, this is the Bootstrap's syntax - framework for CSS, you might want to take a look in it at getbootstrap.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table. Here's my pseudocode

```
<table>
foreach row in result
echo "
<tr>
    <td>result[column1]</td>
    <td>result[column2]</td>
    ... etc
</tr>
"
</table>
```

each tr will make an inline row and the td's will fill it with data from the query.